# SequelizeDatabaseError on existing column during query

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a simple API to fetch data in an existing PostgreSQL table, but for some reason it keeps throwing `'Request failed with status code 501'` with message `'SequelizeDatabaseError: column \"latitude\" does not exist'` in the Postman response when it does exist both in the database and the model.

Here is the database `patient` structure in PostgreSQL:

```
             Column             |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------------------|--------------------------|-----------|----------|---------
 patient_ref_no                 | character(32)            |           | not null |
 gender                         | character varying(20)    |           |          |
 age                            | integer                  |           |          |
 longitude                      | numeric                  |           |          |
 latitude                       | numeric                  |           |          |
 segment                        | character varying(10)    |           |          |
```

Here is the model in `../../models/patient.model`:

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('patient', {
        patient_ref_no: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        gender: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        age: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true
        },
        longitude: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        latitude: {
            type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        segment: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'patient',
        freezeTableName: true,
        id: false,
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
    }
    );
}
```

Here is my sequelize initialization in `../../models/index.js`:

```
import config from '../../config/environment';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

let db = {
    Sequelize,
    Op: Sequelize.Op,
    sequelize: new Sequelize(config.sequelize.dbName, config.sequelize.userName, config.sequelize.password,
        {
            host: config.sequelize.host,
            dialect: config.sequelize.dialect,
            port: config.sequelize.port,
            logging: (...msg)=>console.log(msg),
            pool: {
                max: 5,
                min: 0,
                idle: 20000,
                acquire: 20000
            },
            dialectOptions: {
                dateStrings: true,
                typeCast: true,
                useUTC: false
            },
            operatorsAliases: false,
            timezone: '+08:00'
        })
};

db.PatientModel = db.sequelize.import('../../models/patient.model');

module.exports = db
```

And here is my controller:

```
import { errorJsonResponse } from '../../config/commonHelper';
import { PatientModel } from '../../models'

const {Op} = require('sequelize');

export async function getLonLat(req, res) {
    try {
        const { segmentIds } = req.body;

        const patients = await PatientModel.findAll({
            where: Object.assign(conditions, {
                segment: {  [Op.in]: segmentIds },
                latitude: { [Op.ne]: 0 },
                longitude: { [Op.ne]: 0 }
            }),
            attributes: ['patient_ref_no', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'gender', 'age', 'segment'],
            raw: true
        });

        return res.status(200).json({patients});
    } catch(error) {
        Log.writeLog(Log.eLogLevel.error, `[getLonLat] : ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        return res.status(501).json(errorJsonResponse(error.toString(), error.toString()));
    }
}
```

Above is only the codes I suspect to be problematic, but the actual endpoint function is much more complicated. I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Did you try to output the generated SQL and execute it directly against DB?

Comment: @Anatoly i did, it worked fine and returned expected output. apparently it has something to do with the difference between db in dev and in prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because of the difference between our development and production database and has nothing to do with the codes included in this question. If you encounter the same problem, make sure you get your DB structure and config, especially the **schema**, right. We changed the DB prod to fit DB dev and they work fine now.